# At what point does a company become relevant to have its own tag? Or should they be combined?

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently asked a question about the term Equal Housing Lender being used by p2p lenders. I noticed that there is a tag "lending-club" as well as "lending" and "peer-to-peer-lending" but there is no tag for "prosper" or "on-deck". There are however tags of large financial companies such as "bank-of-america".

Where do we delineate the point at which a company as a tag becomes relevant? At the point of writing both "lending-club" and "bank-of-america" have 12 mentions.

Something I noted was that there as no "wells-fargo". how much value do specific company tags really give (particularly given that over time policies are likely to change not to mention that different locations may vary ex internationally) and at what point does a company tag become relevant? If we do not have both say Wells Fargo and Bank of America does Bank of America really add great value?

I would argue that in most scenarios the company name has little value as a tag and can be outright misleading in regards to what the question is about particularly when we only have a tag for one of the companies involved. (looking at this: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bank-of-america) the specific bank is not all that relevant. Most banking practices are governed by location rather than a specific bank.

Examples include: 
[How long are checks issued by Bank of America valid?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/39609/how-long-are-checks-issued-by-bank-of-america-valid)

This one references both BofA and WF but only has a BofA tag:
[Transfer money between Wells Fargo and BofA accounts for free](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/49149/transfer-money-between-wells-fargo-and-bofa-accounts-for-free)

and this one as well
[How does Wells Fargo use my phone number to find my Bank of America account?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/36179/how-does-wells-fargo-use-my-phone-number-to-find-my-bank-of-america-account)

and this
[Why doesn't Bank of America or Wells Fargo have free ACH push or pull funds transfer?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/10448/why-doesnt-bank-of-america-or-wells-fargo-have-free-ach-push-or-pull-funds-tran)

In terms of p2p lending and lending-club it seems to me that the majority of posts are clearly more relevant to p2p lending rather than a specific company. It just so happens that lending club is the market leader in p2p and thus it appears most people are talking about lending club rather than another company even though it seems most of the info applies to online lending and or peer to peer lending. See: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lending-club.

I feel that company tags are often misused when the question is more about general industry, laws, or practices.

Answer (score 3):

I hadn't noticed those tags.  I agree that it's hard to see why tags for individual companies are needed.  It seems like if the question is so tightly linked to a particular company that a company-specific tag is required, the question is very likely to be too specific to the questioner's individual circumstances to be useful to a wider audience.  (That is, it would likely be a customer-service question for the tagged company.)  In the examples you give, the tags add little or nothing to the question, and I don't see any reason why those tags need to exist.

Comment: exactly, I also question the value if one but not the other exists. Like BofA vs WF